# Android pass include layout ressource id as variable

Tags: android, binding, include

I'm using databinding with a layout that include another, and I would like to pass the ressource id of layout to include as a parameter, so the included layout can be changed programmatically.
@layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="layoutResId"
            type="int" />
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
    </data>
    <android.widget.LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@{layoutResId}"/>
    </android.widget.LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

But i have this issue:
layout attribute must start with "@layout/."

Answer (score 0):

You can add the id in the container layout where your `include` tag resides. For example:

```
<FrameLayout>
    ...
    <include layout="@layout/main"
             android:id="@+id/main_container" --> add id here
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hello @Christilyn, thank you for the answer but it dont change anything.